# Program to get user's details, calculate age and display all information

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have some code started but I am having problems saving the users string input into a variable.

Using ReadString I can get prompt the user to input a string, but after saving the users input into a variable named AskName1, and then displaying the information saved in AskName1, I have found that it save the number of characters that the user input and not the actual string. So what I need to figure out is how to save the string that the user input into a variable instead of the number of characters the user input.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    AskName BYTE "Please enter your name " ,0dh,0ah,0
    Birth BYTE "Please enter your birth year",0dh,0ah,0
    Job BYTE "Pleas enter the location at which you work",0dh,0ah,0
    AskName1 DWORD ?
    Birth1 DWORD ?
    Job1 DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

call Clrscr

mov edx, OFFSET Birth
call writestring

call ReadInt
mov Birth1, eax

mov edx, OFFSET Birth1
call writeint
call crlf

mov edx, OFFSET AskName
call WriteString

call ReadString
; AT THIS POINT I WANT TO TAKE USER STRING INPUT AND SAVE THE STRING INTO THE VARIABLE "ASKNAME1"

main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irvine's [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) needs two arguments in `EDX` and `ECX`. It fills the memory pointed by `EDX` and returns in the size of the input. Since the string in `[EDX]` will be zero-terminated, you have to reserve space for the string and the terminating null. With `AskName1 DWORD ?` you reserved only 4 bytes - that's surely not enough.

As I saw debugging, ECX should be the size of the string **with** null (not as mentioned: *"max number of non-null chars"* = size-1).

Do it so:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    ...
    AskName1 BYTE 16 DUP (0)        ; Reserve 16 bytes and fill them with 0
    ...

.code
...
lea edx, AskName1                   ; EDX = address of AskName1
mov ecx, Sizeof AskName1            ; ECX = size of AskName1
call ReadString
...

; and don't forget:
push 0
call ExitProcess
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Got the program working the way I want it to now.

Comment: @AlexDavis: You're welcome If it answered your question I would appreciate an [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  :-)